# octave: error: rgb2gray: RGB of invalid data type 'logical'

Tags: image, loops, runtime-error, octave, converters

i have octave code who convert image into specific code on a game, it work well until file number 1507

```
% The images must be in the same folder as this script.
% The originY variable will be updated for each PNG file.
originY = 3010000;

% Threshold values modify which shades of grey are consirered scenery (0-255).
threshold1 = 50; %black is 0
threshold2 = 0; %white is 255

% The origin modifies where the rider begins relative to the image.
originX = 200;

% Images can be made larger using the scale option. Use only whole numbers.
% Note that there is a size limit for tracks uploaded to FRHD.
scaleX = 2;
scaleY = 2;

% Loop through each PNG file until 2154.png.
for n = 1505:2154
    % Create the file name for the current PNG file.
    filename = sprintf('%04d.png', n);

    % Read the PNG file.
    image = imread(filename);

    % Create the file name for the output text file.
    outputFilename = sprintf('%04d.txt', n);

    % Open the output text file for writing.
    output = fopen(outputFilename, 'w');

    grayImage = transpose(rgb2gray(image));
    sceneryString = sprintf('#');

    for j = 1:(size(grayImage,2)*scaleY)
        currentColor = 2; % 2 for white, 1 for gray, 0 for black
        for i = 1:size(grayImage,1)
            if originY+j >= 0
                row = lower(dec2base(originY+j, 32));
            else
                row = strcat('-', lower(dec2base(-(originY+j), 32)));
            end;

            if originX+i*scaleX >= 0
                xPos = lower(dec2base(originX+i*scaleX, 32));
            else
                xPos = strcat('-', lower(dec2base(-(originX+i*scaleX), 32)));
            end;

            pixel = grayImage(i,ceil(j/scaleY));

            if currentColor == 2
                if pixel > threshold2
                    continue;
                elseif pixel < threshold1
                    fprintf(output, '%s %s ', xPos, row);
                    currentColor = 0;
                else
                    sceneryString = sprintf('%s%s %s ', sceneryString, xPos, row);
                    currentColor = 1;
                end;
            elseif currentColor == 0
                if pixel < threshold1
                    continue;
                elseif pixel > threshold2
                    fprintf(output, '%s %s,', xPos, row);
                    currentColor = 2;
                else
                    fprintf(output, '%s %s,', xPos, row);
                    sceneryString = sprintf('%s%s %s ', sceneryString, xPos, row);
                    currentColor = 1;
                end;
            else
                if pixel > threshold2
                    sceneryString = sprintf('%s%s %s,', sceneryString, xPos, row);
                    currentColor = 2;
                elseif pixel < threshold1
                    sceneryString = sprintf('%s%s %s,', sceneryString, xPos, row);
                    fprintf(output, '%s %s ', xPos, row);
                    currentColor = 0;
                else
                    continue;
                end;
            end;
        end;

        if currentColor == 1
            sceneryString = sprintf('%s%s %s,', sceneryString, xPos, row);
        elseif currentColor == 0
            fprintf(output, '%s %s,', xPos, row);
        end;
    end;
    sceneryString = sprintf('%s#', sceneryString);
    fprintf(output, '%s', sceneryString);
    fclose(output);

    % Increase the value of originY by 2000 for the next iteration of the loop.
    originY = originY + 2000;
end;
```

error message

> 

```
error: rgb2gray: RGB of invalid data type 'logical'
error: called from
    colorspace_conversion_input_check at line 41 column 7
    rgb2gray at line 61 column 5
    FreeRiderImageMaker at line 31 column 15
```

i try to start it again from 1505, but its still stop at 1507. i change the originY from 0 into 3010000 so the output coordinate is correct, but its still not working, anyone can help me fix this please??

Comment: The error says that the image is not an RGB image. Have you thought of loading that image and checking the type/dimensions?

Comment: the type or the dimension is  same with any other image

Comment: That's not what Octave thinks.

Comment: It probably is a 1 bit PNG (2 gray levels), which MATLAB seems to read in as a logical array. You need to verify type (`islogical(image)`) and number of channels (`size(image,3)`).